# How to compare values in a list with a string?

Tags: python, arrays, random

I want to create a script which should prevent equal sentences. Firstly, I thought that it was enough to just check if the previous and the current sentence are the same. But it turned out that no sentence should be duplicate. My first thought was to create a new list and save the created sentences in it. After that, the program should check if the new sentence is on the list. But it doesn't work at all and I don't know why. I hope you can help me.

*If you find any syntax mistakes it's because I translated the script to English and did a mistake.

```
import random

sentence = ''
previous_sentence = ''
sentence_list = []

def create_sentence():
    names = ["x","y", "z"]
    descriptions = ["a","b", "Dc"]
    global sentence
    global previous_sentence
    global sentence_list



    while sentence == previous_sentence:
        sentence_list.append(sentence)
        name = random.choice(names)
        description = random.choice(descriptions)
        sentence = f'{name} is a {description}'
        if sentence == previous_sentence and sentence in sentence_list:
            name = random.choice(names)
            description = random.choice(descriptions)
            sentence = f'{name} is a {description}'
        else:
            previous_sentence = sentence
            return sentence
    else:
        prevoius_sentence = sentence
        return sentence       

for i in range(50):
    print(create_sentence())
```

Comment: Rather than put the sentence in a list, you could perhaps add the sentence to a `set`. A set does not allow duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrite your code in a bit cleaner way without global variables and to make this code more reusable:

```
import random

def create_sentence(names, descriptions, sentence_list):
    name = random.choice(names)
    description = random.choice(descriptions)
    sentence = f'{name} is a {description}'
    while sentence in sentence_list:
        name = random.choice(names)
        description = random.choice(descriptions)
        sentence = f'{name} is a {description}'
    sentence_list.append(sentence)
    return sentence

def main():
    names = ["x","y", "z"]
    descriptions = ["a","b", "Dc"]
    sentence_list = []

    for i in range(50):
        print(create_sentence(names, descriptions, sentence_list))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

- The `create_sentence()` function uses a `while` loop that continues generating new sentences until a sentence is generated that is not already in the `sentence_list`. Once a unique sentence is generated, it is added to the `sentence_list` using the `sentence_list.append(sentence)` line.
- The function also makes sure that a new sentence is created until it is different from the previous sentence, by checking if the sentence is already in the list before it appends it to the list. This ensures that the list will only contain unique sentences.
- The function `create_sentence()` is separated from the main logic of the program, making it more reusable and easier to test.
- The function takes in the `names`, `descriptions`, and `sentence_list` as arguments, making it more clear what data the function depends on.
- The function uses a `while` loop instead of global variables to keep track of previous sentence.
- The `main` function creates the variables and calls the `create_sentence` function in a for loop.
- The `main` function is wrapped in a `if name == 'main'` block, it allows the code to be imported as a module without running the `main` function.
- The variable and function names are in lower_case_with_underscores, making it more readable and consistent.
- The code is more readable and easy to understand.
- The `if else` block is removed as it's not required.